# Javascript many classes selection

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I´ve got code:

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="content">
    <ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
      <li class="bg4 bleft">
        <div class="heading">Hello!</div>
        <div class="bgDescription"></div>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </li>
</ul>
</div> 
</div>
```

and I need to change text on Hello! on Title and on text. How I could select tags with multiple classes and id's? the codes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bg4 bleft heading').innerHTML="bla";
document.getElementsByClassName('description').innerHTML="bla";
```

doesn´t work

Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('bg4 bleft heading')` won't match anything - classes `bg4 bleft` and `heading` belong to two different elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('accordion bg4 heading').innerHTML="bla";
```

You need not add same classes of a particular html element as you did, but rather use a hierarchal way like above so that you can pin-point the element you need to focus.